# Best platform for gekko

Tags: jupyter-lab, gekko

What is the best platform for gekko that will let you have an interactive graph? I am currently using jupyter lab but it doesnt have animation or show it real time

Comment: What research have you done on your own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an built-in dynamic GUI tool available for simple optimization problems, although it is certainly not fully-featured and is quite buggy at the moment.

You can pull it up using `GUI=True` in your call to `m.solve()`.

Some other favorites used here in the lab are Plotly and Matplotlib. Both of these can be made to support dynamic plotting.